# Backgroud css not working in mozilla

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently developing a website hosted at samgatha.org.
The body background styling is not functioning when opened in mozilla.
Also i have noticed that when i include the doctype tag, the background fails in chrome also.

The website is hosted at samgatha.org.

```
body{
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-image: url('/assets/bgm.png');
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width:100%;
}
```

This is the CSS, i can include additional code on request.

Comment: i have included the css, i thought you could see the page source in the browser.

Comment: Try to add 2 dots on the path `url('../assets/bgm.png');` **or** let the body css on the page header (instead of in the external stylesheet) example `<style> body {.... </style>`.

Comment: Nope.. still not working. My problem is, the same code is working in chrome, but not in mozilla. i would like to know why

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%;` should be `background-size: 100%;`

Comment: background-size:100% 100% is a valid statement. source : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp. Also, when i change it to  background-size: 100%; the  image width is set to 100% and not the height in mozilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `body` needs a height in FF for this to work.

```
body{
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-image: url('/assets/bgm.png');
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width:100%;
 height:100%; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Your solution works. Can you tell me, why there was a difference in chrome and mozilla?

Comment: Not really....I'd guess Chrome assumes a 100% height but FF does not but without doing a full inspection of the code I can't be certain.